# symfony - how to do routing

Tags: php, symfony

I need help with symfony, how to do the routing and add the page to the finished project, this is where I added the new routing: src / BlogBundle / Resources / config / routing_news.yml here is the code:

```
reset:
    path: / reset_mail
    defaults: {_controller: BlogBundle: Page: reset_mail}
```

Then I added to the controller: src / BlogBundle / Controller / PageController.php code:

```
public function reset_mail(Request $request)
{
    $pageRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AdminBundle: reset_mail');
    $page = $pageRepository->findOneBy([
        'path' => 'page / reset_mail'
    ]);

    return $this->render('BlogBundle: Page: reset.html.twig', [
        'title' => $page->getTitle()
    ]);
}
```

Well, I created the file: reset.html.twig in src / BlogBundle / Resources / views / Page. So this is what I did wrong, because when I go to this / page / reset_mail, nothing happens. What I did wrong, and how to do it right?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204897/discussion-on-question-by-stell-symfony-how-to-do-routing).

Answer (score 0):

You should use annotations for your routing.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

It's good practice (https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#don-t-use-annotations-to-configure-the-controller-template).

It's really simple to use annotation and better.

Hope that's will be useful.

Cheers !